# Unable to Install pycrypto

Tags: python, windows-7, installation, mingw32, pycrypto

```
ValueError: invalid version number '2.20.51.20100613'
```

I'm having problems installing pycrypto. Tried package manager: pip & easy_install, didn't work. Tried to manually install it via "python setup.py install", the same error like the above appears.

I've followed the instructions [here](http://blog.sadphaeton.com/2009/01/20/python-development-windows-part-2-installing-easyinstallcould-be-easier.html) and got stuck at installing pycrypto after installing "mingW" gcc, g++ and msys-base (MSYS shell environment)

Not really sure what to do now after several days of trying.

Here's the complete output of the error:

```
C:\Users\Denz\Desktop>pip install pycrypto
Downloading/unpacking pycrypto
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pycrypto
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in ?
      File "C:\Users\Denz\Desktop\build\pycrypto\setup.py", line 340, in ?
        core.setup(**kw)
      File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\core.py", line 149, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 946, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python24\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.14-py2.4.egg\setuptools
\command\install.py", line 53, in run
        return _install.run(self)
      File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 506, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 112, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 253, in run
        force=self.force)
      File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1177, in new_compiler
        return klass (None, dry_run, force)
      File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 292, in init
```

`CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 83, in __init__
    self.gcc_version, self.ld_version, self.dllwrap_version = \
  File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 424, in get_versions
    ld_version = StrictVersion(result.group(1))
  File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\version.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.parse(vstring)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\distutils\version.py", line 107, in parse
    raise ValueError, "invalid version number '%s'" % vstring
ValueError: invalid version number '2.20.51.20100613'`

Comment: Python 2.4? Seriously? Upgrade to a recent version...

Comment: lol. I'm working on an embedded system that forces me to use 2.4. haha, I've no choice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get working windows binaries on [**this page**](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto).

Comment: It works now! I've tried that in the past. Didn't realize that it was installed until I ran; import Crypto. Thanks!